# Why doesn't Maven automatically create a settings.xml file?

Tags: maven, dependencies, cicd

I'm writing an tech article about Maven vs Jenkins, but one thing that came up in my research is the fact Maven doesn't automatically create a settings.xml file. It has to be manually created by the user themselves if they want to change global parameters. Why is that? Does Maven exclusively use values in pom.xml for projects?

So far, I've done my research on how users have to create a settings.xml file. But unfortunately, most of my sources don't explain why this is the case. Most just say, "settings.xml isn't automatically created, the user must create it," and that's it.

Comment: As mentioned the default parameters work. Furthermore where should the `settings.xml` being generated? If you are on a local machine maybe `$HOME/.m2/setting.xml` might be correct. if you are on a CI machine that's simply wrong... apart from things like credentials etc...Apart what is about Maven vs. Jenkins? Sounds wrong? Two different things..

Answer (score 0):

I mean, Maven runs with default parameters if you don't have one, and so it is not mandatory to have one.